# move key to sub array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects grouped by Name like this:

```
[
  {
    Name: 'Color',
    Data:[{Id: 1, Name: 'Red'},
          {Id: 2, Name: 'Yellow'},
          {Id: 3, Name: 'Blue'},
          {Id: 4, Name: 'Green'},
          {Id: 7, Name: 'Black'}]
  }, {
    Name: 'Size',
    Data:[{Id: 8, Name: 'S'},
          {Id: 11, Name: 'M'},
          {Id: 12, Name: 'L'},
          {Id: 13, Name: 'XL'},
          {Id: 14, Name: 'XXL'}]
  }
]
```

I would like to transform this into a heavy array like this:

```
[
  {Id: 1, Name: 'Red', optionName: 'Color'}, 
  {Id: 2, Name: 'Yellow', optionName: 'Color'},
  {Id: 3, Name: 'Blue', optionName: 'Color'},
  {Id: 4, Name: 'Green', optionName: 'Color'},
  {Id: 7, Name: 'Black', optionName: 'Color'},
  {Id: 8, Name: 'S', optionName: 'Size'},
  {Id: 11, Name: 'M', optionName: 'Size'},
  {Id: 12, Name: 'L', optionName: 'Size'},
  {Id: 13, Name: 'XL', optionName: 'Size'},
  {Id: 14, Name: 'XXL', optionName: 'Size'}
]
```

How to do it in javascript/ES6?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.map()`, `.concat()` and `Object.assign()` methods to get the resultant array:

```js
let data = [
  {Name: 'Color', Data:[{Id: 1, Name: 'Red'}, {Id: 2, Name: 'Yellow'}, {Id: 3, Name: 'Blue'}, {Id: 4, Name: 'Green'}, {Id: 7, Name: 'Black'}]},
  {Name: 'Size', Data:[{Id: 8, Name: 'S'}, {Id: 11, Name: 'M'}, {Id: 12, Name: 'L'}, {Id: 13, Name: 'XL'}, {Id: 14, Name: 'XXL'}]}
];

let result = [].concat(
  ...data.map(({Name, Data}) => Data.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, {optionName: Name})))
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` with `array#forEach`.

```js
const data = [ { Name: 'Color', Data:[{Id: 1, Name: 'Red'}, {Id: 2, Name: 'Yellow'}, {Id: 3, Name: 'Blue'}, {Id: 4, Name: 'Green'}, {Id: 7, Name: 'Black'}] }, { Name: 'Size', Data:[{Id: 8, Name: 'S'}, {Id: 11, Name: 'M'}, {Id: 12, Name: 'L'}, {Id: 13,Name: 'XL'}, {Id: 14, Name: 'XXL'}] } ],
      result = data.reduce((r, {Name: optionName,Data}) => {
        Data.forEach(({Id, Name}) => r.push({Id,Name, optionName}));
        return r;
      }, []);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also able to do it using `forEach`. like below.

```js
var s = [{Name:'Color',Data:[{Id:1,Name:'Red'},{Id:2,Name:'Yellow'},{Id:3,Name:'Blue'},{Id:4,Name:'Green'},{Id:7,Name:'Black'}]},{Name:'Size',Data:[{Id:8,Name:'S'},{Id:11,Name:'M'},{Id:12,Name:'L'},{Id:13,Name:'XL'},{Id:14,Name:'XXL'}]}];

var y=[];

s.forEach(x=>x.Data.forEach(z=>{
  z['optionName'] = x.Name;
  y.push(z);
}));

console.log(y);
```